# Instagram: get all media from a hashtag - access_token clarification

Tags: token, instagram, hashtag

I'm creating a web page to get all public images from users with a specific hashtag.
This app will be used in one computer only, in a museum. The page will check if there's any new instagram post with this #hashtag every 5 minutes.

I got an access token following the authentification process described on the site, then I made a request to instagram to get the permission to get the public_content with my access token, which has been declined.
So if I try to use my own access_token, like this

https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/{tag-name}/media/recent?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN

I get

{"pagination":{"deprecation_warning":"next_max_id and min_id are deprecated for this endpoint; use min_tag_id and max_tag_id instead"},"meta":{"code":200},"data":[]}

If I use an access_token generator website and make the same request, it works.

Did someone understand why instagram won't give me an access token that works? 
unlike these third party websites ?

And if I use this access_token provided by a random third party generator, does someone know if it will expire at some point ?

Thanks

Comment: This question is off-topic because it is a customer support request. See: [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746)

Answer (score 0):

You are having this problem because your app is in "Sandbox Mode". Even if you have the `public_content` scope enabled for your token, Sandbox Mode apps can only "see" your past 20 posts. So if the hashtag you're searching for does not appear in your last 20 posts, you will get an empty result set. Check out [this Instagram API summary](https://medium.com/@emersonthis/instagram-on-websites-the-new-landscape-62c91d733894#.psynexzi3) for a better understanding.